# react PWA manifest must have path to html file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps

Currently, I do not have html file instead I am using html.js. However, start_url in the manifest.json seems to take only path to html.

I have been went through may postings from medium which all of them using html. Is this current limit for the pwa ? or there is way to use html.js file as start_url ??

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/static/icon-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: Here is the sample to [set a start URL](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#set_a_start_url). The value of start_url can be anything. `You can now define how your app is launched, add a query string parameter to the start_url that indicates how it was launched.`

Comment: yes I checked but they use html file not javascript file.

Comment: In this case if your website still access via example.com you can use "/" as start_url